# Set up and tear down functions for pytest bdd

Tags: python, bdd, pytest

I'm trying to do setup and teardown modules using pytest-bdd. 
I know with behave you can do a environment.py file with before_all and after_all modules. How do I do this in pytest-bdd

I have looked into "classic xunit-style setup" plugin and it didn't work when I tried it. (I know thats more related to py-test and not py-test bdd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just declare a `pytest.fixture` with `autouse=true` and whatever scope you want. You can then use the `request` fixture to specify the teardown. E.g.:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='module')
def setup(request):

    # Setup code

    def fin():
        # Teardown code

    request.addfinalizer(fin)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My next problem is that I have variables. How do I make these variables declared in the setup function as global variables so that they can be used in all my modules?
For example:  
    dollarConv = 1.23  
    interest = 10.9  
These variables are declared in the setup function. But they are inaccessible  in the other modules like, for example:
@given('I send <x> amount of Switzerland'):
def my_given_function(x):
      SendAmount(x, dollar, interest)

Comment: pytest_bdd is a plugin to pytest. You really need to also be familiar with the facilities provided by pytest to do real testing. In this case you want to delcare a pytest fixture that will available to all of your testing code. You should read up on all this at http://pytest.org/latest/overview.html.

Comment: Thank you so much again and thanks for the link too. Apparently we can also use "global". ie:
global dollarConv and global interest

Answer (score 2):

A simple-ish approach for me is to use a trivial fixture.

```
# This declaration can go in the project's confest.py:
@pytest.fixture
def context():
    class Context(object):
        pass

    return Context()

@given('some given step')
def some_when_step(context):
    context.uut = ...

@when('some when step')
def some_when_step(context):
    context.result = context.uut...
```

Note: confest.py allows you to share fixtures between codes, and putting everything in one file gives me a static analysis warning anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"pytest supports execution of fixture specific finalization code when the fixture goes out of scope. By using a yield statement instead of return, all the code after the yield statement serves as the teardown code:"

See: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html

eg.

```
    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def smtp_connection():
    smtp_connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, timeout=5)
    yield smtp_connection  # provide the fixture value
    print("teardown smtp")
    smtp_connection.close()
```